# How to get the cookie value and put it into the Vuex store after refreshing page in vue

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a product component and I have an I am adding products into cart there:

```
addToCart: function () {
            this.amount = this.itemsCount !== "" ? this.itemsCount : 1;
            if(this.variationId != null) {
                this.warningMessage = false;
                    cartHelper.addToCart(this.product.id, this.variationId, parseInt(this.amount), (response) => {
                        this.$store.dispatch('addProductToCart', {
                            cart: response.data,
                        })
                    });
            } else {
                this.warningMessage = true;
            }
        },
```

And I also have cart helper where I am making my API calls and store the cart_guid in the cookie:

```
let cartHelper = {
    cartCookieName: "_cart",
    cookieValue: "",

    getCart: function (callback = undefined) {
        return apiHelper.getRequest(
            "/carts",
            (response) => {
                document.cookie = `${this.cartCookieName}=${response.data.attributes.cart_guid};`;
                this.cookieValue = response.data.attributes.cart_guid;
                if (callback) { callback(response); }
            }
        )
    },

    addToCart: function (product, variation_id, amount, callback = undefined) {
        if(this.cookieValue == "") {
            this.getCart(() => {
                this._addToCart(product, variation_id, amount, callback);
            });
        } else {
            this._addToCart(product, variation_id, amount, callback)
        }
    },

    _addToCart(product, variation_id, amount, callback = undefined) {
        return apiHelper.postRequest(
            `/carts/${this.cookieValue}/add-item`,
            (response) => {
                document.cookie = `${this.cartCookieName}=${response.data.attributes.cart_guid};`;
                if (callback) { callback(response); }
            },
            {
                product_id: product,
                variation_id: variation_id,
                amount: amount,
            }
        )
    },
   
export default cartHelper;
```

(I didnt write the code where I am storing the cart_guid in the cookie. I dont think it is necessary, it is basically cookieValue)
So when I add the product into the cart, I am storing this data in Vuex. For this my action:

```
export const addProductToCart = ({commit}, {cart}) => {
    commit('ADD_TO_CART', {cart});
}
```

my mutation:

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = (state, {cart}) => {
    state.cart = cart;
}
```

and my state:

```
export default {
    cart: {
        "attributes": {
            "items": [],
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do when I refresh the page, the values in Vuex are lost but since there is still a cookie with the value cart_guid, I should basically make this call and fill the Vuex again with the cart_guid. But I am quite new in Vuex, so I don't know where I should put the logic. I would be really glad if you give me any hint or code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a onMounted lifecycle where the code inside will run whenever the vue component has been successfully mounted onto the DOM. You can put your function where it retrieves the value of your cookie in there so it will after mounted.